# Source code is calling wrong template class function in c++, how to fix?

Tags: c++

I am having a minor problem here and I'm not sure how to rework my code to fix this..This is a question from c++ primer plus as well.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template <typename T>
//#1
T maxn(T array[], int n); // function call always go to this one
//#2  
template <class T> T maxn(char* ptr, int n); // problem is this, I want it to -
// work with array of pointers to strings (char* names[])

int main(){
    char* names[] = {"Bobby", "Jack"};
    int array[] = {5,9,2,11,15}; 
    maxn(array, 5); // call works and goes to #1
    maxn(names, 2); // not going to #2 since it also matches #1 signature...
}
```

Well, I know what my problem is and it's that my call with the array of pointers also satisfy the parameter conditions of #1, but I want it to go to #2..Is there anyway I can get this to happen? According to my exercise I must have a specification of the template class so I cannot just get rid of it..I hope you can understand.

My entire source code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template <typename T>
T maxn(T array[], int n);
template <class T> T maxn(char* ptr[], int n);

int main()
{
   char* names[] = {
               "Zara Ali",
               "Hinaa Ali",
               "Nuha Ali",
               "Sara Ali",
   };
   int array[] = {5,9,2,11,15};
   char* pointer = maxn(names, 4.0);
   return 0;
}
template <typename T>
T maxn(T array[], int n)
{
    T temp;
    temp = array[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(temp < array[j])
            {
                temp = array[j];
                //std::cout << temp;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "hello";
    return temp;
    //std::cout << "Max: " << temp << std::endl;
}
template <class T> T maxn(char* ptr[], int n)
{
std::cout << ptr;
char* pointer;
char tmp = strlen(ptr[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(tmp < strlen(ptr[j]))
        {
            tmp = strlen(ptr[j]);
            char* pointer = &(ptr[j]);
        }
    }
}
return*pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `names` is `char const*[2]`; after conversion to a pointer,
it becomes `char const**`, not `char*`.  You can't call the non-template
function, because there is no conversion from `char const**` to `char*`.

Also, of course, the special version shouldn't be a template, since it
only works for the type `char const**`:

```
char const*
maxn( char const** ptr, int n )
{
    //  ...
}
```

is presumably what you want.  (Otherwise, you'll have to specify the `T`
explicitly, ie: `maxn<T>( names, 22 );`.  For whatever you want `T` to
be.  But since in the template version, `T` must be the pointed to type,
I rather suspect that this is not what you want.)

Answer (score 3):

Add another parameter to the template to only accept array references, not an array parameter degraded to a pointer.

```
template <class T, int N> T maxn(T (&array)[N], int n);
```

Comment: @PiotrS. I didn't test this code, if there's a syntax error you can fix it with parentheses. You can't actually have an array of references.

Comment: @TakShing then you need to have a parameter of `char**`, not `char*`. And you might need a `const` in there too, since you're using string literals.

Comment: Changed my template to template <class T> T maxn(char** ptr, int n); if that is what u mean?

Comment: @TakShing how is compiler supposed to deduce the return type? it shouldn't be a function template at all and it will work.

Comment: @MarkRansom your answer makes little sense even after changing the declaration from *array of references* to *reference to array*, correct me if I'm missing something here

Answer (score 2):

Your type specific overload for an array of pointers to `char` should be declared as:

```
template <size_t N> const char * maxn(const char* (&ptrs)[N], int n = N);
```

Your current declaration takes a pointer to `char` in the first parameter, not an array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: I will try adding the [] in and report results asap!

Comment: It's not working, I will post up my entire source code (pretty short)

Comment: Why this?  He's trying to provide a non-template function.  (And this won't work anyway, since `names` has type `char const*[2]`, so calling your function with it will require a deprecated conversion.)

Comment: What should I be calling it with because after substituting your code and calling char* pointer = maxn(names, 4.0); it always goes to #1

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks. I changed the answer so that the template merely adjusts to the array size, and accepts `const char *`.

Comment: TakShing, I was thrown off by your own templated return result in your own code. You don't really want a template for the return value here. The current answer should work correctly.

Comment: Is my function call correct though? maxn(names, 4);

Comment: The real problem is that we don't really know what he wants.  If the function is only to be called on declared arrays, then using the reference to an array, and dropping the length argument is the best solution.  If he expects it to work in other contexts, where the C style array has already been converted to a pointer, and he's got the size, then it can't be used.  (Of course, the best solution is probably to drop the C style arrays completely, and use `std::vector`.)

Comment: Yes, I do come from a c background, I haven't learned about vectors yet (haven't come across vectors in the guide book yet)..

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree. I am leaving the answer up because it generated a couple of hats.

Comment: It shows a useful technique.  I actually use it most of the time, because about the only time I use C style arrays _is_ for static data, where I want the compiler to decide the size according to the number of initializers (and since C++11 allows that with `std::vector` as well even that may be more of a historical artifact in my code---unless the members are PODs and I want static initialization, to avoid order of initialization issued).